# insert data to mysql using populate dropdown list

Tags: php, mysql

i'm trying to insert data to my database table name dokter and the populate dropdown list from poliklinik. but when i'm trying to insert it,the notification keep showing "undifined vaiable : kodep"

here the form code

```
<select class="form1" name="Kodecrot">
            <?php
            $query = mysql_query("select * from poliklinik");
            if(mysql_num_rows($query) != 0) {
                while($tampil = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                    echo "<option value=".$tampil['Namapoli'].">".$tampil['Namapoli']."</option>";
                }
            }
            ?>
            </select>
```

here the process code

```
<?php
include'../koneksi.php';
$KodeDokter = $_POST['KodeDokter'];
$NmDokter = $_POST['NmDokter'];
$AlmDokter = $_POST['AlmDokter'];
$Telp = $_POST['Telp'];
$KodePoli = $_POST['Kodecrot'];
$KodeJadwal = $_POST['KodeJadwal'];
$med = mysql_query("select * from poliklinik where Namapoli = '$KodePoli'");
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($med)){
    $name = $data['Namapoli'];
    $kodep = $data['Kodepoli'];
}
$jad = mysql_query("select * from jadwalpraktek where Hari = '$KodeJadwal'");
while($data1 = mysql_fetch_array($jad)){
    $jadwal = $data1['Hari'];
    $jaks = $data1['KodeJadwal'];
}
mysql_query("insert into dokter(KodeDokter, NmDokter, AlmDokter, Telp, Kodepoli, KodeJadwal)values('$KodeDokter','$NmDokter','$AlmDokter','$Telp','$kodep','$jaks')");
?>
```

Comment: this query `select * from poliklinik where Namapoli = '$KodePoli'` not returing anything

Comment: print_r($_POST);    r u sure u r getting this: $_POST['Kodecrot']

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated..

Comment: Your code is vulnerable for [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php), and the mysql_ extension is deprecated and is removed in PHP 7. Consider switching to PDO or mysqli.

Comment: may $med query will not return any row, or if you want display the value($kodep) even the query has not return any value, just declare that variable to NULL or anything. That is declare before the while loop

Comment: and by the way the primary key of poliklinik is Kodepoli